# Not Storing Web Cookies or Logs

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, web, ip-address

Sorry this is my first question here not sure if it really belongs. However, I was wondering if it would be possible for my website to not store any cookies and IP addresses at all. Would it be possible to not store any logs that contain IP addresses of the users?